# Datalist in HTML form read all values with python

Tags: python, html, cgi, datalist

Is there a method to read all the values of a datalist with python?

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/file.py" method="post">
<div>
<label for="name">
    Name
</label>
<input type="text" name="name" list="namelist" id="name">
  <datalist id="namelist">
    <option value="1">
    <option value="2">
    <option value="3">
    <option value="4">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

with python i am able to read the selected value through the command

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name=form.getvalue("name")
```

but is there a way to put all the values in a list? ['1','2','3','4']

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you can read the original page.  The browser isn't sending you all possible values.

Comment: and is it possible to select in the form all the items of the datalist?

Comment: No, with "option", only one can be selected.  If you can change the HTML, you could add a hidden field with the data you need.  But watch out, the user can meddle with that.  What is the need?  Your website is responsible for that form, you know what the possible values are.

Answer (score 0):

```
liist=[]

with open("filename",'r') as m:

    for x in m:
        if "value" in x:
           final=x[19:20]
           liist+=final
print(liist)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.